# Reactjs Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '-/project/reactapp/node_modules/sass'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, fs

I'm working on my reactapp on localhost.

I received this error message during the compilation of my app on localhost.
'Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '-/project/reactapp/node_modules/sass'.'

My webpack version is >5.

Comment: Node v5? That's extremely old. It's not a good idea to directly edit the package.json of dependencies as they'll get overwritten eventually.

Comment: Sorry it's about webpack version. What's your solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I succeed to manage this error by opening the package.json file inside of the 'sass' folder that is in 'node_modules' folder that is in the root user folder (and not in the app folder)
for Mac copy paste the following path with your own username file:///Users//node_modules/sass/package.json

and add the following code:

```
"browser": {
   "fs": false
}
```

And do the same in the 'node_modules/sass' that is inside of your reactapp folder : /Users/username/projectname/reactappname/node_modules/sass/package.json

And that's it.

Comment: This works good job @KHOUIEL Salah, but I would love to know why is this a problem from the creators. If anybody has such a resource, reply here.